# How can i delete multiple address book contacts in iOS programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, contacts, addressbook

Hi i have a requirement to show all address book contacts in tableview. if the user wants to select the multiple contacts delete those selected contacts.for this i didn't found any solution for that please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:
You need `#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>`:

```
-(void) removeContactWithRecordsList:(CFArrayRef) selectedRecords_ {
    ABAddressBookRef addressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    if (selectedRecords_ != NULL)
    {
        int count = CFArrayGetCount(selectedRecords_);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            ABRecordRef contact = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(selectedRecords_, i);
            ABAddressBookRemoveRecord(addressbook, contact, nil);
        }
    }
    ABAddressBookSave(addressbook, nil);
    CFRelease(addressbook);
}
```

**EDIT:**
Example: As my case I want to remove all contacts have name "Sample"

```
NSString *searchName = @"Sample";
ABAddressBookRef addressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFStringRef nameRef = (__bridge CFStringRef) searchName;
CFArrayRef  allSearchRecords = ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressbook, nameRef);
[self removeContactWithRecordsList:allSearchRecords];
```

Comment: i am new to iOS can you please send me any example code briefly.

Comment: In did select row i have created check mark and none, when multiple selection is done then it will save 'YES' in the dummy array.         [celselectedd replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"YES"];          In the delete action I will delete the datasource and array in using the dummy array indexes but the problem when i selected the rows in a indexs

Comment: So.. you can get all contacts record  you you selected? right? you just only remove these with [self removeContactWithRecordsList:yourSaveRecords];

Comment: In did select row i have created check mark and none, when multiple selection is done then it will save 'YES' in the dummy array.         [celselectedd replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"YES"];          In the delete action I will delete the datasource and array in using the dummy array indexes but when i selected the rows in a indexes like 2,5,8(Alternate) it is deleting properly. when i selection 2,3 or 5,6 it deleting only one

Comment: I can't get you, sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71641/discussion-between-ajay-km-and-huy-nghia).